# How to create a top generic racf profile from rexx

Tags: zos, rexx, tso, racf

So i'm definig users to racf on a z/OS (ADCD version at my university) using a rexx script. Therefore i want to create top generic profiles for the users in order to secure their datasets. Say i'm creating a user called TEST1.
Therefore i would use

```
ADDSD 'test1.*' UACC(NONE)
```

to create the top generic profile. If i issue the command from tso all works fine. But if i issue the command from my rexx skript, racf creates a profile
named "myusername.test1.* instead of "test1.*" So somehow my username is added as the HLQ when creating the profile. Does any one know why that happens and how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: When you say "issue the command from TSO" do you mean at the READY prompt or in batch via IKJEFT01?  When you say "issue the command from my Rexx script" are you using ADDRESS TSO to issue the command?  Have you looked at the RACF documentation at https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.ich/ich.htm ?  Have you tried issuing a PROFILE NOPREFIX command prior to issuing your RACF command?

Comment: Yes i mean at the READY promt. In my script i enclose the command in quotation marks, so rexx passes it on the the host command environment which is TSO. I have looked at the documentation but had a hard time finding what i'm looking for. i guess it's because i'm new to the "mainframe vocabulary". I havn't tried ADDRESS TSO or PROFILE NOPREFIX yet. But the later sounds promissing, i will try both. Thanks for the reply and sorry for my undetailed question

Answer (score 0):

issuing `"PROFILE NOPREFIX"` before the command solves the problem.
TSO Adds your prefix to any dataset name that is not fully qualified. 
At the end of the skript you should reset your profile prefix with

```
"PROFILE PREFIX("USERID()")"
```

thanks cschneid